# Number of maxima and minima

Tags: calculus

> Let $f: R\xrightarrow{} R$ be defined as $f(x) =|x|+|x^2-1|$. What is the total number of points at which $f$ attains either a local maximum or local minimum?

My attempt:

Broke the function as text

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
 x^2-x-1 , &\text{if $x\leq -1$} \\\
-x^2-x+1, &\text{if $-1\leq x \leq 0$} \\
-x^2+x+1, &\text{if $0\leq x\leq 1$}\\
 x^2+x+1 ,&\text{if $x\geq 1$.}
\end{cases}$$

Clearly from here on differentiating the number of maxima/ minima should be 4 as there are four functions and they are all continuous and derivable. But the answer given is 5...Any reason why

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bcdgieccaq

Comment: Hint: find the local maxima and minima one intervals where the function is differentiable. The points where function possibly is not differentiable should be checked seperately.

Comment: I see... The function is not derivable at -1, 0,1

Comment: How should I proceed if the interval has non differentiable points? I mean check for those points. I am kinda clueless there

Comment: @GENESECT Just substitute $x$ into $f(x)$ for the non-differentiable points. There's only $3$ of them so it shouldn't take more than a few seconds.

Comment: Here's a visualization: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x)+%3D+%7Cx%7C+%2B+%7Cx%5E2+-+1%7C